# audio currentTime returning 0 and not the current time

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm having an issue where I'm using this plugin:

I have created an abstract with the following code, and trying to read from the default `<audio>` and not the plugin. The plugin puts a visibility:hidden on the `<audio>` tag but I don't think that should affect anything.

Here's my code, it's for a slideshow, displaying images at certain intervals in the audio file:

```
 var audio = $("audio");

        audio.audioPlayer();

        // Slideshow
        var slideshowAudio = audio.data("slideshow"),
            slideshowAudioId = document.getElementById("audio-default");

        if (slideshowAudio == "1") {
            var audioTime = Math.floor(slideshowAudioId.currentTime);

            // console.log("Current Time: " + currentTime);

            var slideshow = [];

            $(".slideshow li").each(function () {
                var id = $(this).data("slideshow-id"),
                    time = $(this).data("slideshow-time");

                slideshow.push(time);
            });

            console.log(slideshow);

            $(".audioplayer-playpause").on("touchend click", function () {
                setInterval(function() {
                    alert("show " + audioTime);

                    for (i = 0; i < slideshow.length; i++) {
                        if (slideshow[i] == currentTime) {

                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
```

Comment: which plugin is `this plugin` - I see no plugin, I see dead people, I mean, javascript code

Comment: oh ... you mean the value of var `audioTime` is zero when you try to alert it in the on touchend click callback? of course it is. `audioTime` is set once, outside that function, presumably when the page loads, and never updated ... `audioTime` is not "automagically" updated with `slideshowAudioId.currentTime` - if you want `slideshowAudioId.currentTime` then use `slideshowAudioId.currentTime`

Comment: To have the `currentTime` of an audio tag. You audio has to have a song playing. If there is a song playing and you can't get the currentTime. Try `document.createElement("audio");`

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry forgot to include it: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/04/responsive-touch-friendly-audio-player/

Yes the audioTime is zero. How do I get it to update an retrieve it?

Comment: you need to retrieve the time within the setInterval callback - you could simply put `audioTime = Math.floor(slideshowAudioId.currentTime)` at the top of that callback